# How to remove border of tabcontrol in winform

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpanel, tabpage

I have a tabcontrol and on my `tabcontrol` which is vertically aligned i have borderlike this http://prntscr.com/bdfh0j between each tabs. I wish to remove these border of the tabcontrol like this http://prntscr.com/bdfhwa . Which property can help me achieve this ?

Any idea how it can be acieved ?

Comment: You can't, the look-and-feel is hardbaked into the Visual Style renderer for the control.  If you insist on it looking like that then consider flat buttons in a FlowLayoutPanel and UserControls for the pages.

Comment: You could use a separate control for the navigation - I think you can configure the tab control to not have the "thumbs" - maybe not. In the old days we used to place controls off the screen and move them onto the screen to simulate tabs. You could use groupboxes host the controls and your nav control to move them around. PITB to edit the "tabs" but it works. How to you get the buttons on the left and the text horizontal?

Comment: @HansPassant , Ok could you please elaborate a bit more? i couldn't understand.

Comment: I would also be interested in an answer to this. @HansPassant's has a good idea, but that is a hack and probably would come with all sorts of usability headaches. Sadly you can't even override it with the DrawItem event.